# Modify desktop icon

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-icons

I just installed ubuntu 20.04 with a nice sddm theme.
On the desktop I have a link to an internal folder and another link to an internal html file.

They are using the basic icon set. How can I modify the icon of those links for these 2 shorcuts?